# Tipos de datos personalizados en una sesion typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express-session

tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo un backend con typescript, y cuando quiero desestructurar una sesión de express sessions me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya definí mis tipos de datos en express session así:

```
declare module 'express-session'{

    interface SessionData{
        user: string,
        loggedIn: boolean,
        data: {
            [ key : string ] : any
        }
    }
}
```

así:

```
declare module 'express-session'{

    interface SessionData{
        user: string,
        loggedIn: boolean,
        data: {
            name: string,
            rol : string,
            user : string
        }
    }
}
```

y así:

```
declare module 'express-session'{

    interface Data {
        name: string,
        rol : string,
        user : string
    }

    interface SessionData{
        user: string,
        loggedIn: boolean,
        data: Data
    }
}
```

Pero sigue sin funcional, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?, agradezco de ante mano, gracias.

Comment: Y de las 3 definiciones de SessionData, ¿Cual usas? La última es la que parece correcta. Si pudieras compartir el código de la función donde destructuras.

Comment: La última, y sigue sin funcionar